# Why would the open command cause a memory allocation failure?

Tags: memory, fortran

I am writing some fairly simple code using gfortran. It checks a numeric array for values that exceed certain limits and then writes their location to a flag file if they do.

My problem occurs when I use the open command like so;

```
open(unit=16,file='flags_maxmin_'//TRIM(flnm)//'.txt')
```

`flnm` is an input to be incorporated into the file name (something like `info.dat` or `info.txt`). I receive an error stating

```
Operating system error: Not enough space
Memory allocation failed
```

I have no idea why this would happen as I have used this same method in other subroutines without a problem and I have at least 3 gigs of free RAM and the numeric array I am testing is only a 6x10 of real numbers.

I have tried getting the `iostat`. It has worked successfully once (when I deleted the file and set `status='new'`) and returned a value of 17.

Does anyone understand why this would cause a memory allocation error?

Comment: Several possibilities. But, because the operating system is involved, the first one could be a disk full or almost full.  Another possibility : too many opened files simultaneously even if I would expect another message. What is your compiler ?

Comment: I am using gfortran, `gcc version 4.8.0`. In parentheses it says `experimental`. Also, this is on a windows computer. 
I opened the task manager and my disk usage is less than 5% when I run my code.

Comment: I played with other (unrelated) parts of my code and the open command is no longer causing a memory allocation failure. 
I am going to assume I was doing one of the things listed by Francois Jacq, and didn't realize it.